# Pagination in Oracle using refcusror

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Pagination in stored procedure with sysrefcuror for getting data from two tables.

Comment: Yes, you described the solution. What is preventing you from coding it?

Comment: I'm using string query for getting data that is written in single quotes and I'm confused where to add these lines. help me should i use inside string query or at the end before end of procedure where I'm opening refcusror.             my query is like myquery varchar2(1000);     myquery:='select *from -------';   open sysrefcuror for myquery;   where to apply this formula l.

Comment: I would suggest you add (to the question) a simplified example of the procedure so we can spot the issue.

Comment: check my comment now.

Comment: begin
my query varchar2(1000);
myquery:= 'select *from emp';
open sysrefcuror for myquery;
end;

Comment: A query for pagination in Oracle 12+ looks like `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... OFFSET ... ROWS FETCH NEXT ... ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: my query for getting data is a string query inside single quotes so can i use this offset and fetch with that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code and additional information to the question, not to the comments, and either indent each line of code at least 4 spaces so we can read it. Thanks!